# Assigning data returned from a promise to an external variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following code inside a render function in react

```
let newCat
this.props.client.query({
  query: queryCategoriesForCategoryListPage,
  name: 'fetchCategories',
  variables: {
    incubatorId: this.props.getCurrentUser.currentUser.incubator._id
  }
}).then((cat)=>{
  console.log("cat resolved is: ",cat)
  if(cat.data && cat.data.categories)
    newCat = cat.data.categories
})
console.log("newCat is: ",newCat)
```

the cat variable inside the .then seems to be behaving correctly but newCat seems to be undefined , how can i fix that?

Comment: Both the stringified version and the normal version that i've written work as expected and print actual output

Comment: The promise is **asynchronous**. You can't access the data until the promise resolves inside `then()`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GxWteFh , the promise got resolved in the `.then()`